# Best way to Unzip multiple specific folders in 1 zip file using shell/batch

Tags: shell, command-line

It is not a problem, but I would like a better way to do this.

Tried to add multiple lines to unzip some folders

```
unzip Backups/Backup.zip 'okey*' -d ''
unzip Backups/Backup.zip 'sadface*' -d ''
unzip Backups/Backup.zip 'kaka*' -d ''
```

I would like maybe to put everything in one line or something, reduce some code and may be simple and wont use many resources.

Comment: You're using one tag which is generally associated with Unix and another with Windows_. As Windows doesn't generally carry an `unzip` command, I have removed the [tag:batch-file] tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple files (and multiple wildcards) in one [`unzip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) command.

```
unzip Backups/Backup.zip 'okey*' 'sadface*' 'kaka*'
```